# spring-boot compile use jdk 1.7 but run use 1.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-6

I compile spring boot application using jdk 1.7 to application.jar file, but when I run application.jar on machine that installed jdk 1.6, this error is occured

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/saifiahmada/spring/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.saifiahmada.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>dashboard tsd</name>
<description>dashboard tsd</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.2.0</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.9.2</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>2.1.1</webjars-jquery.version>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration> -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

thanks

[edit]
to @Saurabh, I change dependency in my pom.xml for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, like this :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your POM looks OK. Are you sure it is Maven creating the class files (maybe you have the project open in an IDE as well)?

Comment: As @DaveSyer said, looks like it was not compiled with java 1.6 but with java 1.7 (version 51.0 means java 7, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)). Perhaps you are building it with some other tool. Or did you build it with `maven clean package`?

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak : you are right, I use mvn package command to compile this spring boot application to make jar file. 



thank all

Comment: @DaveSyer  : yes, I sure

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're having is that one of your dependencies requires some jar that is compiled against Java 7 (javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please have a look at this, which describes how to run Spring Boot on Java 6:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6

The important bit quoted here for reference:

"While the Java Transaction API itself doesn’t require Java 7 the official API jar contains classes that have been built to require Java 7. If you are using JTA then you will need to replace the official JTA 1.2 API jar with one that has been built to work on Java 6. To do so, exclude any transitive dependencies on javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api and replace them with a dependency on org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final"

Also have a look here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements

I do realise that you are using Spring Boot 1.2.1 and all my references are for 1.2.2, but it seems likely that this issue existed back in 1.2.1 as well and 1.2.1 is already not available for download anymore, so you may want to consider upgrading. But you will run into trouble with Java 6, so you may as well think about upgrading your environment.

FWIW, you don't even need these lines in your pom.xml:

```
<maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

Comment: thank for your advice and references, 
I do change my pom.xml with exclusion javax.transaction-api  on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and add jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec dependency,
and, I do downgrade my jdk to openjdk 6, and build my application using mvn package command, so far it running well on jdk 6

thank all

Answer (score 0):

Newer Java versions are compatible with older Java versions, but not the other way around. So, you cannot normally run code compiled with JDK 7 on a Java 6 runtime environment.

The best way to make sure it works on Java 6 is to use JDK 6 instead of JDK 7 to compile your code.

That means you will have to [download and install JDK 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html), and make sure that it is being used when you compile your code instead of JDK 7. (Note: JDK 6 is not supported anymore by Oracle, you can still download it but Oracle requires that you create an account in order to download it).

Comment: In my experience you can most definitely run code compiled with a JDK 7 on a Java 6 runtime, as long as the compiler target is set to Java 6.

Comment: Ok, but that will still not prevent you from using APIs that exist in the Java 7 standard lib but not in Java 6 - you'll notice them only at runtime when you get `NoClassDefFoundError` or `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: That's correct. But that's not what he's seeing, he's seeing "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0", and that's a class file that's compiled for Java 7, and in this particular case it's "javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar" pulled in by one of his dependencies. He may well have other issues after that if he uses Java 7 APIs, we can't tell from what he has posted though.